# Why crontab on Centos 7.8 for reboot the server once generate e reboot loop?

Tags: centos, cron, reboot

i want run a CronJob for reboot the server once or twice at month.
I do:

```
crontab -e
```

than:

```
51 9 5 * * /usr/sbin/reboot
```

This should reboot at 5 day of the month at 9:51, it works the server is reboot but after 30 seconds the reboot continue generating an infinite loop.

Why this happen and how to fix?
The only way i have to stop this is remove the CronJob so I'm unable to set an automated reboot once a month.

Any help will be appreciated.

Update 1:
The issue is not caused by the too short time of the cron, even if i add +5 minutes or delay the reboot still happen in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by the click not synchronized.

I resolved by doing a cron that run before the reboot with the following command:

```
/sbin/hwclock --systohc >/dev/null 2>&1
```

than

```
/usr/sbin/shutdown -r +5 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

works.

Without the command mentioned to sync clock the issue persist.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming it is due to a too fast reboot, i.e. the time is still 9:51 when the cron daemon comes up again, so the job is triggered.

One way to work around this would be to delay the actual reboot with `sleep`:

```
51 9 5 * * sleep 60 && /usr/sbin/reboot
```

Or, use `shutdown` instead, with a delay:

```
51 9 5 * * /usr/sbin/shutdown -r
```

`shutdown` delays the action for a minute by default, but you could use `+5` as an argument to delay further. The benefit of using `shutdown` over `reboot` in this case is that logins will be denied during the delay (except for root) and that users will get a warning of the impending reboot.